# Issue with MySQL and SequelizeJS

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

When I save a new record to the database my date gets updated...

In my input : `15/02/2016`

In my database : `2016-02-14 23:00:00`

My code :

```
postSubmit: function (request, response) {
  var self = this;

  var event = request.body.event;    

  event.start = (event.start) ? moment(event.start, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00") : null;
  event.end = (event.end) ? moment(event.end, 'DD/MM/YYYY').format("YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00") : null;

  self.eventDao.save(event, function(modelError, event){
    if(modelError){
      response.redirect('/event/submit');
    }else{
      response.redirect('/');
    }
  });
},
```

Comment: Which timezone are you in? Could it be that moment.js translates local time to UTC before submitting it?

Comment: When I put `new Date()` in the chrome dev tools : `Mon Feb 15 2016 15:36:59 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)`

Comment: Are you using the TIMESTAMP data type in the MySQL table? If so change to DATETIME

Comment: I'm using `datetime`. Is that possible that a date with time set to `00:00:00` could be the issue?

Comment: `2016-02-15 00:00:00 GMT+0100` is the same time as `2016-02-14 23:00:00 UTC`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, and the issue was about hours, I have to set hours and minutes.